# Why when applying a radius change for making object to rotatearound it's showing exception error transform.position assign attempt for is not valid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Apllying the radius change in runtime is working fine but i want to change the radius also in the Start()

When calling the method ApplyRadius in the Start it's showing this exception :

transform.position assign attempt for 'Cube (1)' is not valid. Input position is { 39.383492, NaN, -24.138273 }.
UnityEngine.Transform:set_position (UnityEngine.Vector3)
RotateAroundPoint:Update () (at Assets/RotateAroundPoint.cs:50)

Line 50 is :

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, height, time / delay), transform.position.z);
```

The code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objToRotateAround;
    [Header("The axis by which it will rotate around")]
    public Vector3 axis;
    [Header("Angle covered per Second")]
    public float anglePerSecond;
    [SerializeField] private float radius;
    public float upperLimit;
    public float lowerLimit;
    public float delay;

    private float height;
    private float prevHeight;
    private float time;
    private float lastRadius;

    private void Start()
    {
        ApplyRadius();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Check if the radius was changed
        if (!Mathf.Approximately(radius, lastRadius))
        {
            ApplyRadius();
        }

        time += Time.deltaTime;
        if (time > delay)
        {
            prevHeight = height;
            height = Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);

            time = 0;
        }

        // Rotate with a frame-rate independent angle per second
        transform.RotateAround(objToRotateAround.transform.position, axis, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);

        // For the Lerp you want a factor between 0 and 1
        // not between 0 and delay
        // => divide by delay gives you a factor between 0 and 1   
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, height, time / delay), transform.position.z);
    }

    private void ApplyRadius()
    {
        // Get the dorection vector from the pivot to your current object position
        var direction = (transform.position - objToRotateAround.transform.position).normalized;

        // set your object in the same direction but at distance of radius
        transform.position = objToRotateAround.transform.position + direction * radius;

        lastRadius = radius;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that your input position y is NaN, since you are using time in your calculation maybe it's a timescale issue.
You could try making sure timescale is set to 1 before getting your time value.

```
Time.timeScale = 1f;
```